# Prevent body clicks on certain dom elements

Tags: javascript

I have a click listener on my body:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){

});
```

It's there so when a user clicks the body of my site or any other element, any open pop up is closed.

But I want to prevent clicks on the pop up (apart from the X button) from triggering the event.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the `e.target` it gives you the element where click event has generated. If its popup element, do nothing

Answer (score 5):

You need to prevent event bubbling. To do so, use `event.stopPropagation ()`, which will stop propagating the click event to elements further up in the DOM (e.g. the body).

So in your case, it would be something like:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Close modal
});

specificOtherElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation ();
    // Do other stuff eventually
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation for further details.